# How to setup Smart search and result display for Custom table?

Tags: kentico

I have `Custom table` and `Smart search index` for it. Index type is *Custom tables*. Custom table has transformation for displaying table record.

What I need to do (Portal Engine development model) to:

1. Add search web part and what web part to use?
2. Display search results?

For now, I am using `SmartSearchDialogWithResults`. In `Indexes` I selected appropriate custom table search index and in `Transformation name` custom table transformation.

When I try to search - correct number of results and html formatting from transformation are present but no data.

Maybe this ***is not possible*** through ***Portal Engine development model***?

There is transformation (transformation type: *ASCX*):

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="border-top">
      <td class="max-width-117">Name:</td>
      <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Phone: </td>
      <td><%#Eval("Phone")%></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email:</td>
      <td>
        <a href="mailto:<%#Eval("Email")%>"><%#Eval("Email")%></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is render result:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="border-top">
      <td class="max-width-117">Name:</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Phone: </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email:</td>
      <td>
        <a href="mailto:"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this problem after short searching and help from colleague.

The answer is simple: Yes, this **is possible** with Portal Engine development model. According to provided example: you need to use `GetSearchValue` instead of `Eval` in transformation.